# How can I center a label now that XAlign is no longer supported?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the code I was using:

```
 <Label x:Name="detail3" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="35" XAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
```

But I understand XAlign should no longer be used.

Comment: Use `HorizontalTextAlignment`

Answer (score 7):

`XAlign` has been deprecated for the better named `HorizontalTextAlignment`

Similarly `YAlign` has been deprecated for `VerticalTextAligment`

So to horizontal align the text for your `Label` you can do the following:

```
<Label x:Name="detail3" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="35" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
```

See https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Label/

> **HorizontalTextAlignment**
>
> Center, End, or Start, to indicate the
>   horizontal placement of the label text.
>
> **VerticalTextAlignment**
>
> Center,
>   End, or Start, to indicate the vertical placement of the label text.

Comment: However, stupid question, does it work over Android, iOS and UWP? Because if I'm right, in the past, I had to make a renderer for that..

Comment: Should work on all 3 platforms. Probably when you had to make a `custom renderer` it was probably a work around for a bug in `Xamarin.Forms`

Answer (score 0):

Please check Xamarin documentation
[Xamarin.Forms.Label.XAlign Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.XAlign/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to Label control in centre align use the -HorizontalOptions="Centre"

```
<Label x:Name="detail3" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="35" XAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Centre"  LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
```

If you want to Label's text in centre align use the -HorizontalTextAlignment="Centre"

```
<Label x:Name="detail3" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="35" XAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Centre"  LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
```